# Google Plus Android, Update Status & Change Profile Picture

Tags: android, google-plus

Please someone let me know any APIs If present in google plus through which I can post status and change profile picture in Android. For Posting status I found Share Post but that isnt what I require as in I dont want to open any new window to update my status instead an API call which directly does this..please help! thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Sharing to Google+ will have to be done using the [Google+ UI](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/). There is no direct API to do it within your UI.

There is no API method to update a profile photo. You can [open an issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) if you would like to see such a feature added.